# Как отменить последние коммиты git?

Tags: bitbucket, git

Как можно отменить последние 5 коммитов в git?

Схема работы такая:
В phpstorm сделал 5 коммитов на бедро, затем push, после чего на стороне сервера стянул эти изменения в проекте и все побилось. Как на стороне сервера отменить последние 5 pulls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так понимаю, вам на стороне сервера нужно не только файлы откатить, но и сам репозиторий. Поэтому приемлем такой вариант.

```
# выполняем на локальном репозитории
# стоит создать ветку-бэкап для неудачных коммитов
git branch backup
git reset --hard HEAD~5
# и теперь push --force
git push --force origin mybranch

#потом на сервере приводим файлы в соответствие с последним коммитом
git reset --hard
```

Более общий вопрос и ответ: [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/181472)

Answer (score 6):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~5
```

Я надеюсь, что правильно понял, что нужно отменить 5 коммитов, а не "5 pulls". Посмотрите внимательно, возможно, что придётся откатить ещё merge commit.

Разделяйте систему контроля версий и деплой. Почитайте про capistrano.

Comment: Нужно отменить "5 pulls" с ведра

Comment: 5 pulls отменить не получится, потому что информации о том, сколько именно pull'ов вы делали, не хранится, кроме того редкого случая, когда вы делаете merge commit на каждый pull.

Вы можете отменить несколько commit'ов тем способом, который я указал.

Comment: а зачем? Сделайте реверт коммитов и все, иначе только push --force, но это плохая идея - всем, кто уже сделал пулл, придется восстанавливаться вручную. В этом случае лучше аккуратно revert сделать (как вариант `git checkout COMMITID -- *` (может, force нужно будет сделать, не знаю) `git commit -am "sorry i'm idiot, pushed to production by accident :("`

Comment: Версия, во-первых, не продакш, а dev. Во-вторых, `git checkout COMMİTİD - *` дает: `fatal: invalid reference: COMMITID`. Так и не понял - что можно в таком случае сделать

Comment: аааа COMMITID это номер коммита последней хорошей версии и не `-` а `--`

Comment: >  сколько именно pull'ов вы делали, не хранится

ну не совсем, немножко все таки хранится. смореть `git reflog`.

Comment: Ребята - как можно отменить push?

Comment: я попробовал git revert <commit>, пишет, что не обновилось